# Calculated Columns: Returning a value depending on parent curency column value

Tags: list, calculated-column

Morning all,

Here's what I'd like to achieve and I'm hoping that you fine folk can help me with this.

I have a currency column in a customised list, with values ranging from £1k - £20k.  I'd like to take the value of this field within a calculated column and return a number 1 - 5 depending on what the value is.

My logic would be something like: -

- £1k - £4k returns a 5
- £5k - £8k returns a 4
- £9k - £12k returns a 3
- £13k - £16k returns a 2
- £17k - £20k returns a 1

Is is possible to achieve this within a formula?

Cheers,
Steven

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
=IF(AND([Column1]>1000, [Column1]<4000), 5, IF(AND([Column1]>5000, [Column1]<8000),4, IF(AND([Column1]>9000, [Column1]<12000),3,IF(AND([Column1]>13000, [Column1]<16000),2,IF(AND([Column1]>17000, [Column1]<20000),1,0)))))